# Saved pages on browser

Tags: samsung

I am using basic internet browser on my Samsung galaxy GT I8262, if I cleared storage data of google search then will it affect to the saved pages on browser? Will the saved pages get deleted?

Comment: Why not take the backup and try yourself? And what is "basic internet browser"? It should be having a name and a version.

Answer (score 0):

Internet app is separate from Google search app so clearing data of Google search won't affect your saved pages